# Selected image Orientation in canvas in WP8.1 SL

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am selecting an image from my WP device using FilePicker and I want to set that image as a child of a canvas. Here Bmp is a bitmapImage formed from the selected storage file.

```
_img.Source = Bmp;
_img.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
(sender as Canvas).Children.Add(_img);
```

What I got to do this, I should get the orientation of the selected image so that I can set it inside the canvas perfectly.

I tried setting the below, before I add the child to canvas.

```
Stream stream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
Bmp.DecodePixelHeight = 700;
Bmp.DecodePixelWidth = 450;
Bmp.SetSource(stream);
```

storageFile is selected file from the device.

This is fine, if the image is portrait. But I need to set DecodePixelHeight 
 and DecodePixelWidth according to the orientation.

I apologize if the question is dumb!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try don't set DecodePixelHeight and DecodePixelWidth. Next set image stretch as None.